# Uncaught Error calling method on NPObject

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, methods, applet, call

The question is - why does this specific applet fails to run under: 
Google Chrome 22.0.1229.94 (Official Build 161065), OS Linux, WebKit 537.4, JavaScript V8 3.12.19.15, Flash 11.4.31.110, Java SE 6 Update 37, Linux 3.2.0-32-generic, 64-bit.

[image]

I must say that this applet runs well in 32-bit environment under linux and windows.

I also have another applet which runs well in a problematic 64-bit environment which leads me to conclusion, that the failure caused by an attempt to call applet method from the javascript function.

I have also tried different tag - object, but nothing changed. The applet source code is fine too (it runs well on different environments).

How can I fix it?

Comment: I don't know if that is somehow cut off or not. Your code has not any `<head></head>` and `<body></body>` markup.